# Find index of an element when there are multiples of the element in a list

Tags: groovy

I have a list that says this:

```
def availFood = ["${property['Cake']}", "${property['Custard']}", "${property['Donuts']}"]
```

When we println that list, it looks like this:

```
[true, true, false]
```

I'm trying to say "for each true value, do a bunch of stuff". And I did it like this:

```
for(currentFood in availFood){
    if (currentFood == "true"{

    //Find out the index of the current food to figure out which one it was
    def foodNum = availFood.indexOf(currentFood)
    def foodName = ""
    //a big if statement for 0 = "Cake", 1 = "Custard", 2 = "Donuts"
    println("Our current food is ${foodName}!")

    }
}
```

However .indexOf will return the index of the first value that matches currentFood, not the index of the element currentFood. Meaning since index 1 and 2 are both true, `availFood.indexOf(currentFood)` will always return `1` which will give me the wrong foodName.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you really want the code in idiomatic could look like so:

```
def property = [ Custard:true, Donuts:true ] // fake out your property

def availFood = [ 'Cake', 'Custard', 'Donuts' ]

availFood.eachWithIndex{ foodName, foodNum ->
  if( !property[ foodName ] ) return
  println "Our current food is $foodName / $foodNum!"
}
```

prints

```
Our current food is Custard / 1!
Our current food is Donuts / 2!
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna mark this as the answer bc essentially I had to a variation of what you suggested. Good to learn you can't iterate through lists in groovy the way you can in Java. Also, you cannot do a for(x in map) or Jenkins will through a "non serialization exception". Good to know, thank you!

Comment: In groovy you can do everything you can do in java, especially in groovy 3

Comment: Maybe it's because my company's Groovy ver isn't up to date, or maybe it's a Jenkins issue really and I don't know enough. But my same issue is documented here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-49732 where one must use a map.each{ key, value -> } closure instead of a for (x in map) { x.key, x.value} because of the differences in groovy/java serialization. And unlike Java, when you do a for(x in list) (like my question), x.indexOf(list) doesnt produce the same results in groovy vs java. Groovy gives the first match, java gives x index. It's all a little different(or maybe im too new)